Como cargar contenido de vistas parciales en div html con asp netcore y ajax
Estimados buenas tardes , por favor su ayuda con un problema que tengo en asp netcore cuando trato de enviar un viewModel que tiene 1 lista y 1 objeto y ambos van a 2 vistas parciales 1 para cada objeto. El problema es que cuando el controler envía correctamente los objetos al viewModel y a cada vista parcial, cuando me retorna las vistas parciales con la información, el ajax no me está mostrando esas vistas parciales en los div html si no que me genera una vista nueva y sin diseño pero con el json de respuesta.

Aquí dejo el codigo
Clase SvtResponsable
Model
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SofTiVet.Models
{
public partial class SvtResponsable
{
    public SvtResponsable()
    {
        SvtMascota = new HashSet<SvtMascota>();
        
    }
    public SvtResponsable(int IdResponsable, string RutResponsable, string NombreResponsable, string ApellidosResponsable, string FonoResponsable, string? DirResponsable)
    {
        this.IdResponsable = IdResponsable;
        this.RutResponsable = RutResponsable;
        this.FonoResponsable = FonoResponsable;
        this.NombreResponsable = NombreResponsable;
        this.ApellidosResponsable = ApellidosResponsable;
        this.DirResponsable = DirResponsable;

    }
    public int IdResponsable { get; set; }
    public string RutResponsable { get; set; } = null!;
    public string NombreResponsable { get; set; } = null!;
    public string ApellidosResponsable { get; set; } = null!;
    public string FonoResponsable { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? DirResponsable { get; set; }

    public List<SvtResponsable> ListResponsable { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SvtResponsable> SvtResponsables { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SvtMascota> SvtMascota { get; set; }
}
}

Clase SvtMascota
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SofTiVet.Models
{
public partial class SvtMascota
{
    public SvtMascota()
    {
        SvtControls = new HashSet<SvtControl>();
        SvtExamenes = new HashSet<SvtExamene>();
        SvtHistorials = new HashSet<SvtHistorial>();
    }

    public int IdMascota { get; set; }
    public string NomMascota { get; set; } = null!;
    public string SexoMascota { get; set; } = null!;
    public string EspecieMascota { get; set; } = null!;
    public string RazaMascota { get; set; } = null!;
    public string ColorMascota { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateTime FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
    public string Chip { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? NumChip { get; set; }
    public int SvtResponsableIdResponsable { get; set; }

    public virtual SvtResponsable SvtResponsableIdResponsableNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ICollection<SvtControl> SvtControls { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SvtExamene> SvtExamenes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SvtHistorial> SvtHistorials { get; set; }
}

}
Controller
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetInfoClinica(string? Rut ) 
    {

        if (Rut == null)
        {
            SvtResponsable svtResponsable = new SvtResponsable();

            var Lstresponsable = _context.SvtResponsables.ToList();

            if (Lstresponsable == null || !Lstresponsable.Any())
            {
                // Log or debug information here to ensure this isn't null
            }
            
                var viewModel = new ViewModel
                {

                    ListResponsables = Lstresponsable
                };

            var partial1 = await RenderPartialViewToStringAsync("_TableResponsable", viewModel);
            var partial2 = await RenderPartialViewToStringAsync("_TablePacientes", viewModel);

            return Json(new
            {
                partial1 = partial1
                partial2 = partial2
            });

        }

        else
        { 
        var responsable = await _context.SvtResponsables.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.RutResponsable == Rut);
        var idResp = await _context.SvtResponsables.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IdResponsable == responsable.IdResponsable);
        PacienteController mascota = new PacienteController();
        List<SvtMascota> mascotas = mascota.GetPaciente(idResp.IdResponsable, _context);

        var viewModel = new ViewModel
        {
            ListaMascotas = mascotas.ToList(),
            svtResponsables = new SvtResponsable
            {
                IdResponsable = responsable.IdResponsable,
                RutResponsable = responsable.RutResponsable,
                NombreResponsable = responsable.NombreResponsable,
                ApellidosResponsable = responsable.ApellidosResponsable,
                FonoResponsable = responsable.FonoResponsable,
                DirResponsable = responsable.DirResponsable
            }
        };

            var partial1 = await RenderPartialViewToStringAsync("_TableResponsable", viewModel);
            var partial2 = await RenderPartialViewToStringAsync("_TablePacientes", viewModel);

            return Json(new
            {
                partial1 = partial1
                partial2 = partial2
            });
            
        }
    }

 private async Task<string> RenderPartialViewToStringAsync(string viewName, object model)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = _viewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, false);

            if (viewResult.View == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"The view '{viewName}' was not found.");
            }

            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                ControllerContext,
                viewResult.View,
                ViewData,
                TempData,
                writer,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );

            await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
            return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }

Vistas parciales
_TableResponsable.schtml
@model ViewModel;

<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
<thead>
    RESPONSABLE

    <tr>
        <th>Rut Responsable</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellidos</th>
        <th>Dirección</th>
        <th>Teléfono</th>
        <th>Email</th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

</thead>
<tbody id="table-responsable">
    @if (Model!=null && Model.ListResponsables != null && Model.ListResponsables.Any())
    {
        @foreach (var itemResponsable in Model.ListResponsables)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>itemResponsable.RutResponsable)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>itemResponsable.NombreResponsable)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>itemResponsable.ApellidosResponsable)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>itemResponsable.DirResponsable)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>itemResponsable.FonoResponsable)</td>
                <td></td>

                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
    }

</tbody>

_TablePaciente.schtml
@model ViewModel;


<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
<thead>
    PACIENTES


    <tr>
        <th>ID Mascota</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Especie</th>
        <th>Sexo</th>
        <th>Raza</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Tiene Chip</th>
        <th>N° Chip</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

</thead>
<tbody id="tabla_atenciones">


    @if (Model!=null && Model.ListaMascotas != null && Model.ListaMascotas.Any())
    {
        @foreach (var itemPaciente in Model.ListaMascotas)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> @itemPaciente.IdMascota)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> @itemPaciente.NomMascota)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> @itemPaciente.EspecieMascota)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> @itemPaciente.SexoMascota)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> @itemPaciente.RazaMascota)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> @itemPaciente.ColorMascota)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> @itemPaciente.FechaNacimiento)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> @itemPaciente.Chip)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> @itemPaciente.NumChip)</td>


                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
    }
    else
    {
        <p>No hay mascotas disponibles.</p>
    }

</tbody>

Codigo js
function getResponsableByRut(rut) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetInfoClinica", "Clinica")',
            data: { Rut: rut },
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                $("#div-table-responsable").html(result.partial1);
                $("#div_table_atenciones").html(result.partial2);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.error("Error: " + error);
            }
        });
    }

La vista debería renderizarse en la pagina principal donde están los divs donde se verá cada tabla
Clinica.cshtml
<div class="accordion-item">
                            <h2 class="accordion-header">
                                <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
                                    <ion-icon name="person" class="ion-icon"></ion-icon>
                                    Datos del Responsable
                                </button>
                            </h2>
                          

                            <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                                
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="accordion-body">Datos del dueño de la mascota </div>

                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            
                                            <button type="button" id="btn-buscar" class="btn btn-primary" >Consultar</button>
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"> </span>
                                            <input class="form-control" id="txtRut" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese el dato que desee consultar">
                                            <button type="button" class="abrirModalRegResponsable btn btn-primary">
                                                <i class="bi bi-plus-lg"></i>Registrar
                                            </button>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="container-fluid" id="div-table-responsable">

                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion-item">
                            <h2 class="accordion-header">
                                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
                                    <ion-icon name="paw" class="ion-icon"></ion-icon>
                                    Datos del Paciente
                                </button>
                            </h2>
                            <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                                <div class="accordion-body">Ingrese los datos del paciente</div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Consultar</button>
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"> </span>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese el dato que desee consultar">
                                        <button type="button" class="abrirModalRegPaciente btn btn-primary">
                                            <i class="bi bi-plus-lg"></i>Registrar
                                        </button>
                                    </div>

                                </div>


                                <div class="container-fluid" id="div_table_atenciones">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

En los div div-table-responsable y div_table_atenciones es donde debería mostrarse las vistas parciales pero no se muestra en los divs.
aqui la pagina donde deberian verse

en esta vista debería cargarse la info como en el ejemplo

Por favor su ayuda, aun no me funciona.

Que podría estár pasando que no envia la info de las vistas parciales en el div?
